# Why it is said WS-Addressing is not for HTTP?

Tags: web-services, http, ws-addressing

In many places, read WS-Addressing is not built for HTTP? HTTP don't need asynchronous communication? What if A sends request to B and want B reply to C?

Like:

> [What is WS-Addressing good for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7875133/what-is-ws-addressing-good-for) the reply said "But wait... HTTP connection? Why should I care about that? "

The "WS-Addressing for Developers" section of [this introduction](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/entarch/ws-addressing-intro-087619.html) from oracle said "... WS-Addressing is not a revolution. Because an HTTP request and response occur synchronously over a single HTTP connection ..."

Comment: I think you need to clarify this question, possibly by adding a citation for where you've seen this statement, but it might be this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7875133/what-is-ws-addressing-good-for) can give you some insight.

Comment: Add two links.. Cheers!

Comment: You might have an interesting question here but as it currently stands it is difficult to tell what you are asking. Please make an effort to improve your question and make it more clear.