# SOAP Pooling Advantages / Disadvantages

Tags: web-services, soap

I am doing some research on SOAP, for a personal project, and I came across a website with a list of pros and cons for using SOAP, and I understood what most of them meant, except for this one under disadvantages:

> SOAP is typically limited to pooling, and not event notifications, when leveraging HTTP for transport. What's more, only one client can use the services of one server in typical situations.

From my understanding of pooling, there should be no issue pooling a SOAP Object for re usability. Pooling is simply a way to use the same resources over and over again, like a connection to a database. Also not entirely certain on the context of Event Notifications.

So my two questions here are, what does the above block quoted text actually mean, and is this information correct?

Website: http://searchsoa.techtarget.com/definition/SOAP

Comment: I think it's a spelling error, it should say 'polling' and not 'pooling'.  You are right, pooling has a totally different meaning.

Comment: @KrisPeeling THAT makes more sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOAP is [RPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call), and in RPC some local client invokes a method on some remote target and receives a result. That's how it works, so SOAP works that way too. A client invokes a service asking for something and the service just responds.

If you want "events" in this type of communication the most simple approach is to invoke the service more often (i.e. polling). This has the advantage that nothing changes for the server or the client. It's the same RPC call but done more frequently.

These days everyone is connected to the web and everyone is subscribed to all sorts of services. They want to get notified as soon as something happens to the world around them. Pooling becomes inefficient in this sea of users and services because you are wasting resources. You might poll a service a hundred times just to get back one notification. For this reason technology is evolving so that resource use is minimized. And the direction this is moving to is push services.

Now almost everything happens in the browser. Every browser manufacturer rushes to implement the latest technology changes and HTML5 spec. This means actual pages that push notifications to users instead of faking it with Ajax, comet, etc.

SOAP has been around since 1998 and it's not moving as fast as the rest of the web, mainly because SOAP is mostly an enterprise player and because it's a protocol. Because it's a protocol you have to make new technology available to it without breaking that protocol. Things move slower so people have abandoned SOAP in favor of other ways of doing server-client communication.

> SOAP is typically limited to pooling, and not event notifications...

That is correct. But be aware that "typically" does not mean "always".

You can have events, but it's harder. It involves using [WS-* specifications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_service_specifications) like [WS-Eventing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bwill/2004/02/10/ws-eventing-for-dummies/) and [WS-Addressing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7875133/what-is-ws-addressing-good-for). This is a change in the way SOAP clients operate because a client now becomes some sort of a service too because it needs to receive calls too, not just initiate them. If your technology stack implements these specifications then good for you, but if it doesn't, then you have to build it yourself and it's a real pain.

So for these reasons, if you don't have blocking performance or resource usage issues, you "typically" chose doing polling with SOAP and not event notifications.