# SOAP request that takes an awful long to reply - Any idea to stop the connection dropping

Tags: http, soap

I send a SOAP request to update the database. It takes a long time.

Obviously it is over HTTP - so I tried two things

- Increase the timeout.
- Make it a persistent connection.

Here are the problems:

- Increasing the timeout means that if it fails, it may take a long time to discover this - we are talking about an hour to process the request
- Making it persistent - This may timeout as well.

Is there any mechanism to keep the connection alive for extended periods of time? My research has not generated any fruitful results.

Any insights is much appreciated.

Comment: Why does it take an hour to update a database? That's what you should look into. If not an option, then do you really want to keep the connection opened for that long? Do you control the service too? Can you make this asynchronous in some way? Like polling from time to time to see if a result is available or the operation is still ongoing? Or maybe use [WS-Addressing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7875133/what-is-ws-addressing-good-for) or [WS-Eventing](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/bwill/ws-eventing-for-dummies) and have the service contact your client when done?

Comment: It is updating a lot of information. We have checked the performance and we have got it as best as we can (AWR/ASH reports are good). It is such a lot of information to be updated